# How to Select an UIImageVIew on Tap or Touch Begin event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have two buttons Add Images and Edit.
from Add Images i m adding multiple images from gallery and can move each imageview on view.
I have made an Draggable class to move each imageview.

```
@interface Draggable : UIImageView {
    AppDelegate *objectDelegate;
    CGPoint startLocation;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) AppDelegate *objectDelegate;
@end

@implementation Draggable
@synthesize objectDelegate;

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Retrieve the touch point
    objectDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    startLocation = pt;
    [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self];
}
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    // Move relative to the original touch point
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.origin.x += pt.x - startLocation.x;
    frame.origin.y += pt.y - startLocation.y;
    [self setFrame:frame];
}
@end
```

and that how i added images.

```
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] init];
image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
CGRect cellRectangle;
cellRectangle = CGRectMake(20 ,50,image.size.width/6 ,image.size.height/6 );

//[[self view] addSubview:blockView];
UIImageView *dragger = [[Draggable alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle];
[dragger setImage:image];
[dragger setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

[self.view addSubview:dragger];
```

now on Edit button i want to edit that particular image to b selected on single touch. like i have 3 images picOne, picTwo and picThree. if i  touch picTwo and click Edit i want picTwo to edit (open aviary editor).

What i did to do that i have added this line on Draggable touches begin

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == objectDelegate.selectedImageViewFromCanvas)
    {
        // selestecImageViewFromCanvas is UiImageView.
        NSLog(@"dragger");
    }
```

But that statement is always false. 
I hope everyone get it what i want. Thanks

Comment: Zohaib please use gesture recognizer code it will work very easily. For moving any objects..

Comment: Ok i wil try now. but cant i select image the way i m working now?

Comment: ok i will try gesture code for sure

Comment: Have you written this line :objectDelegate.selectedImageViewFromCanvas=self; in your touches began.

Comment: i did but its not working. cant assign self to UIImage.

Comment: yOU CAN ASSIGN IT IN touchesBegan of dragger

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19713/discussion-between-arpit-parekh-and-zohaib)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Arpit . i have used gesture recognizer [link](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/) . i have edit this code. on imagepicker i have set tag on UiView (holderview) and UIImageView (imageview) and when i tap on image then i can get tag value of that holder [sender view].tag . and from that tag i am getting that UIImageView tag like [sender view].tag + 1 ( coz if my holderView tag is 101 than my UIImage tag is 102. )